# GStreamer Code Flow

Tags: gstreamer

It's bit difficult to track the code flow in Gstreamer. For example if you write 'c' code, it has sequential command execution so that you know that which statement is going to execute after which one. However in Gstreamer there is no sequence and most of the times it's bit difficult to understand the code flow.

Comment: ....ok.. And your problem is?

Comment: How to know the sequence of code. i.e. from start to end.

Comment: Yes, multiple threads and event loops are difficult to track.

Answer (score 0):

Take a log with debug level 9 and search for change_state in a logs.so you will come to know from where does the state transition for elements in a pipeline start.From there onward try to understand the code with debug logs.i.e try to understand the code with respect to state transition of element.

Above approach is useful if you are trying to resolve the bug only.But if you want to understand the gstreamer thoroughly then first you need to know the GOBJECT which is nothing but C with OOPS concept.Try to understand the hierarchy of element you want to debug.i.e understand inheritance in gobject first,how function overriding is happened and there is one more mechanism called chain mechanism.if you understand these basic mechanism then gstreamer code flow is just like other c/c++ code flow